# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes on startup, but recovery mode->resume boot works

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel

My **Ubuntu 16.04** desktop has some annoying issue. When I boot up and choose **Ubuntu 16.04** it freezes after some seconds (after the Ubuntu ····), showing some funny graphical pattern on the screen (repetitive, like a lot of color boxes) -my guess, some driver screwing things up-, and can't even do anything to unlock it but to press reset button (no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> nor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, etc. seems to work).

Maybe kernel panic?

But if I choose **Advanced->recovery mode->resume** normal boot it works like a charm.

Also, as I'm on dual boot, Windows works well.

Thanks.

Comment: Update: updating to 18.04 solved this.